# Solving $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$ with L'Hôpitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}
$$

L'Hôpitals rule says: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

This gives us: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)} \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{d \sin^2(x)}{dx}}{\dfrac{d (1-\cos(x))}{dx}} \rightarrow\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Where am I failing?
WolframAlpha computes (the correct answer according to solutions): $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)} \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{d \sin^2(x)}{dx}}{\dfrac{d (1-\cos(x))}{dx}} \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 2\cos(x) = 2\times1=2 $$

Comment: $(\sin^2 x)' = 2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't anything more complex than that..
Cheers, Raoul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use l'Hospital...or a little trigonometry and algebra:

$$\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{1-\cos x}=1+\cos x\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1+1=2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin^2(x)}{1-cos(x)}
$$

L'hospitals rule says: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

This gives us: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin^2(x)}{1-cos(x)} \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{d sin^2(x)}{dx}}{\frac{d (1-cos(x))}{dx}} $$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2cos(x)sin(x)}{sin(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 2cos(x)$$

$$= 2cos0 = 2$$

Comment: What you say l'H rule says is inaccurate (at best). What it actually says is, under the usual conditions of differentiability, indeterminate form and etc., that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\;\;\text{exists}\;\implies \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\;\;\text{also exists and both limits are one and the same}$$